# Optimization problem alignment

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, aligned

I was wondering how to correctly align the following problem at the first letters of each line (`minimize` needs to be aligned with `such`), as well as at the `=` and `\in` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\minimize}{minimize}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{aligned}
            &\minimize_{s}  &J(s) &=\frac12 \langle s,s \rangle \\
            &\text{such~that} &s &\in S.
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding an extra brace group `{\minimize_{s}}` should resolve the issue, but there is probably a better way.

Comment: Thank you, @PeterGrill. That solves the problem.

Comment: I see no reason for aligning `=` and `\in`. Usually “s.t.” in optimization problems expands to “subject to” rather than “such that”.

Comment: @egreg: OK, thank you for the remarks.

Comment: I think the formula should be self contained and be written as `\[ \min_{s in S} J(s) \]`.  `\min` exists already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In light of @PeterGrill's comment, a solution for the problem would be as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\minimize}{minimize}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        &{\minimize_{s}}  &&J(s) = \frac12 \langle s,s \rangle \\
        &\text{such~that} &&s \in S.
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]